# Multiple inheritance, How to avoid manual inherence by copy past and maintenance?

Tags: c#

My  WCF Web Service library expose 2 services on differents endpoints:

```
public interface ICommons
{
    string Common();
}

public interface IFooA : ICommons
{
    string SayFooA();
}

public interface IFooB : ICommons
{
    string SayFooB();
}
```

And their respectives implementations:

```
public class Commons : ICommons
{
    public string Common() => "Common";
}
public class A : Commons, IFooA
{
    public string SayFooA() => "FooA";
}

public class B : Commons, IFooB
{
    public string SayFooB() => "FooB";
}
```

I wanted to have a 4th interface, a test one that will expose all methods in order to test them with out any reference juggling.

And I can define it like :

```
public interface I_A_B : IFooA, IFooB
{
}
```

But the issue is on the implementation on this contract. I wanted to use base class inheritance in order to be sue that I use the same implementation without copy past and maintenance. 
Just like `class A` use `class Commons`, and any change in the implementation of `Commons` will be inherited in `A`.

```
public class A : Commons, IFooA
```

But multiple inherance is impossible  (ref msdn [Why doesn’t C# support multiple inheritance?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/why-doesnt-c-support-multiple-inheritance/))
, so the following line cause error.

```
public class A_B : A, B, I_A_B
```

How can I have an implementation of `interface I_A_B : IFooA, IFooB` that use the most of `class A : Commons, IFooA` and `class B : Commons, IFooB` with the minimum code copy past?

Comment: Have you considered composition over inheritance?

Comment: I prefer composition over inheritance on any kind of behavioural needs (like any methods). I use inheritance only for properties as much as I can. But it is coding you know. Depends on needs and circumstances =)

Comment: I think that I must to inherit from the test interface as it's an WCF Webservice. As I will have the `contract="interface"` in the Web.config. But I can implement it using composition. Big thanks.

Comment: @ilkerkaran `I use inheritance only for properties as much as I can`  What does this mean?

Comment: Usually interfaces, are the way to handle multiple inheritance. implement IFooA and IFooB, instead of inheriting A and B. But you already did. So just delete A, B. Usually you hide the classes A and B from everywhere and deal only with the interfaces.

Comment: @Amy, I personally prefer to use inheritance on dummy classes like DTO classes that contain only properties. Other than that I tend to avoid using inheritance on classes. Hope this clarifies my point. Since I can't edit my previous comment. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such way to expose such a WCF interface (as suggested above in the comments) would be to have:

```
public class A_B : I_A_B {

    [Import]
    public IFooA A {get; set;}

    [Import]
    public IFooB B {get; set;}

    public string SayFooA() => A.SayFooA();
    public string SayFooB() => B.SayFooB();

...
```

implementing the IFooA methods through A, and the IFooB methods through B. Of course, as your link suggests, you have to manually decide which implementation will call the "Common" method.

Answer (score 2):

While Composition over Inheritance can solve your problem, and the community favors such ways of writing code, it could lead to repeating yourself when it does not make sense to re-write functionality. [Check drawbacks section in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

So if you want to test using such a class, then it makes sense to me that such an implementation should be something you need. If an interface like this does not make sense to implement, then why test it in the first place?

If it does, then I'm sure you have some class implementing it already. If we are talking about unit testing, then make sure that you test each method individiually for each class.

A real life examply would be

```
public class A : Commons, IFooA
public class B : A, IFooB
```

And now you have an example of how such a case would be implemented.

Of course, if your case is indeed one of composition and you are not at one of the caveats of Composition over Inheritance, go ahead and do it that way. It makes more sense from a DI perspective as well.